# How to select several columns from a dataset

Tags: list-manipulation, simplifying-expressions

I have a dataset with 20 columns. For a analysis I need all columns except the columns 9 and 11. What I do is:

```
data[[All, {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,  10,   12,13,14,15,16,18,18,19,20}]];
```

My question: is there a smarter way to do this

Comment: Try something like `ds[All, Cases[Range[20], Except[9 | 11]]]`

Comment: `Part[data, All, Complement[Range[20], {9, 11}]] `

Answer (score 9):

```
data = ConstantArray[Range[20], 5];
MatrixForm[data]
```

[image]

You can use `Delete`:

```
Map[Delete[{{9}, {11}}]] @ data // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Alternatively:

```
data[[All, DeleteCases[9 | 11] @ Range[20]]] 
data[[All, Delete[{{9}, {11}}] @ Range[20]]] 
MapAt[Nothing &, data, {All, {9, 11}}] 
Module[{d = data}, d[[All, {9, 11}]] = Nothing; d] 
Transpose @ ReplacePart[ {{9}, {11}} -> Nothing] @ Transpose @ data
ReplacePart[data, {_, 9 | 11} -> Nothing] (* thanks: WReach *)
```

Comment: +1 `ReplacePart[data, {_, 9 | 11} -> Nothing]` would work too.

Comment: thank you  @WReach. Added your suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a `Dataset` with capital D:

Using `Drop`:

```
dataset = Dataset[{
    <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1}|>,
    <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {2, 3}|>,
    <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {3}|>,
    <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {4, 5}|>,
    <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {5, 6, 7}|>,
    <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {}|>}];

dataset[All, Drop[#, {2}] &]
```

[image: Output]

`{2}` would be `{{9}, {11}}` in your case.

Comment: `Drop[#, {9, 11}]&` would drop columns 9, 10 and 11. `Drop` works with ranges, not indices. You'd need `Delete[#, {{9}, {11}}]&` if you want to keep column 10.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Thanks, good catch!

Comment: Or: `dataset[KeyDrop @ "b"]`